# Results of stlf forecast prediction intervals change each run

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, seasonality, exponential-smoothing

Using stlf from [Rob Hyndman](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/159/rob-hyndman)'s forecast package in R, I have noticed that the prediction intervals change each time I run it on a specific series of data (stays the same on other time series data as it should).

Here is the call:

```
msts(x ,seasonal.period = 365.25/7) %>%
stlf(h = 10, method = "ets", etsmodel = "ZZN", damp = T, lambda = 0)
```

However, everything else stays the same.

1. Each time the method stays the same "STL +  ETS(M,Md,N)"
2. The point forecasts are identical
3. Model parameters are identical

Two things solve this problem:

1. Set the seed before running
2. Take off the "lambda = 0" condition, the forecast intervals stay the same.

I would like to figure out why this is happening so I don't need to use these solutions, but get at the heart of the problem.

Session Info:

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] rootSolve_1.6.6  Hmisc_3.17-1     ggplot2_2.2.1    Formula_1.1-2    survival_2.38-3  lattice_0.20-33  forecast_5.9     timeDate_3011.99 zoo_1.7-12      
[10] tidyr_0.3.1      lubridate_1.3.3  readr_0.1.1      dplyr_0.4.3
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that the model you get for the seasonally adjusted series is ETS(M,Md,N). For that model, there are no known algebraic results for computing prediction intervals. Consequently, the prediction intervals need to be selected using simulation. Hence, there is an element of randomness about them.

Later versions of the package do not allow for that model (multiplicative trend often produces poor forecasts).

Comment: Sorry for off-topic; could you please take a look at this Meta issue https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5044 - I think your expert opinion would be important there.